# Returning SQL-query results in Clojure?

Tags: mysql, clojure

I'm learning Clojure and I have a question about the basics.

How can I make the function to return the "rows" variable:

```
(defn list-domains []
  (sql/with-connection db
    (sql/with-query-results rows  ["select * from domains"]
        rows)))
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long time since [I've played <sup>[FR]</sup>](http://www.chicoree.fr/w/Premiers_pas_avec_Clojure) with [clojure](/questions/tagged/clojure), but as far as I remember, `sql/with-query-results` does not *return* result. It merely evaluate a *sub-expression* (the last parameter) with the query result as a parameter:

```
(defn list-domains []
  (sql/with-connection db
    (sql/with-query-results rows  ["select * from domains"]
        (do-something-with rows) )))
```

If you really want to *return*, you could try to instantiate the sequence by using [`doall`](http://clojure.github.io/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/doall):

```
(defn list-domains []
  (sql/with-connection db
    (sql/with-query-results rows  ["select * from domains"]
        (doall rows) )))
```

---

EDIT: Hum ... well ... as a matter of fact, this is the exact same solution as provided by the documentation for [`with-query-results`](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.sql/with-query-results) :/

Comment: The documentation for [http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/doall](doall) is quite confusing in my opinion, but I will try this and see if I get it working.

Comment: @bluekirai I'm not sure this will help but ... sequences in Clojure are *lazy*. That means values are retrieved "as needed". `doall` just force the evaluation of each and every items in the sequence to produce a "real" list of values.